# How to calculate average length of consecutive numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column that has different numbers ranging from `0` to `100` down the rows. Each of them are separated by six blank rows.

So, like this:

```
12





65





47





33

etc
```

---

What I want to do is display an average number of how many numbers there are in a row that are under the value of 50. For instance, 12, 35, 14, 16, 73 would be 4 consecutive numbers, then after the 73 might be 6 consecutive numbers under the value of 50.

I'm trying to calculate what the average length of consecutive numbers is.

I've looked all over the place, but can't find anything related to this.

Comment: Is there any reason why there are six blank rows between each number?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Just making sure I understand what you want -- do you want the average streak of numbers that are less than 50 in a long list of numbers? For example, for a list that has one streak of 4 numbers below 50 and then one more streak of 6 numbers below 50, you want a formula that can return the average of 4 and 6?

Comment: Suppose I take your data, then from 12 to 73 there are 4 values less than 50 and you left 6 blank cells between each set of numbers so will be 24. Therefore the possible numbers fall between 12 to 73 are 24 different values, and their Average will be 24. Is this you are trying to calculate ? OR you are suppose to count numbers which are less than 50 to count their Average in you r case are 4 so Average of consecutive numbers will be 4?  Please confirm !!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure if I understand what you're asking to do, but I think you want to count how many numbers less than 50 occur in succession in your data column A, and then find the average of those counts.

If I've misunderstood, please comment below or edit your question to explain in more detail.

The easiest way to do this is to use a "helper" column to mark the numbers less than 50.  This formula, filled down from B2 in the table below, does that while also ignoring blank cells.

`=IF(A2="","",IF(A2<50,"Mark",""))`

Note that I've reduced the number of blank rows between data values from 6 to 1 for clarity.

Next, this formula, filled down from C2, counts the number of successive occurrences of "Mark" in the helper column.

`=IF(B2="Mark",IF(OFFSET(B2,2,0)="",COUNTIF(B$2:B2,"Mark")-SUM(C$1:C1),""),"")`

**Note:** To adjust this formula for 6 blank rows between data values, change the `OFFSET()` function to `OFFSET(B2,7,0)`

This formula looks for places in the helper column where there's a "Mark" *and* the next possible place for "Mark" is blank.  In those positions, it counts the total of all the "Mark's" in the helper column so far, minus the sum of the counts of all prior groups of "Mark's".

Finally, the average of the Counts is calculated with `=AVERAGE(C2:C38)`.

I hope this helps, and good luck.

[image]